# How to create an ActionScript 3.0 in Flash to display Current Date, Time and Day of Week

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to create a new ActionScript 3.0 file in Flash that will include the Current Time, Date and Day of the week. I am able to complete the script separately (Time and Date) and (DayofWeek) but when combining I receive line errors 1120:Access of undefined property time. I am not a GURU but am a pretty fast learning. I would appreciate any help that can be provided to me. Also I would like for the time to display AM\PM and to show in double digits for numbers ranging from 1-9 with a "0" added. Thank you in advance

Here is my code below

```
var looper:Timer = new Timer(100);
looper.start();
looper.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, looptime)

function looptime(event:TimerEvent):void{
    var dayOfWeek_array:Array = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"); 
    var today_date:Date = new Date();
    var month:Number = time.getMonth()+1;
    var day:Number = time.getDate();
    var year:Number = time.getFullYear();


    var day_str:String = dayOfWeek_array[today_date.getDay()];
    var hour:Number = time.getHours();
    var minute:Number = time.getMinutes(); 

    Day_txt.text = day_str;
    Date_txt.text = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;
    if (hour > 12){
        Time_txt.text = hour-12 + ":" + minute;
    }else if (minute < 10){
         Time_txt.text = hour + ":" + "0" + minute;
    } else {
         Time_txt.text = hour + ":" + minute;
         }
    //Time_txt.text = hour + ":" + minute;

    }
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't defined `time`. Shouldn't it be `today_date`?

Comment: Hello I do have today_date:Date = new Date(); in the above code. When creating the Date\Time separately from the Dayoftheweek. I used var time:Date = new Date(); which works fine. and for the daysoftheweek script I used var today_date:Date = new Date(); which also works fine. I just dont know enough about actionscript to write the code together so that they all display in my movie clip and not one or the other. Hope this helps clarify it a bit. Im very new to this and was able to create these by doing a lot of reading but was not able to find a fix for combining the two.

Comment: In the code you've posted above, the variable time is undefined. Where do you define time?

Comment: Here is a helper class I wrote when AS3 first came out,  perhaps going through it will help you understand how to do this. (or if you're not interested in learning you could just use put in your project directory and use it directly) - http://pastebin.com/26rQxkfC

Comment: The above class I posted has one dependency, this class: http://pastebin.com/YUeiLkix

Comment: Thank you but I cant seem to access them. It appears to be blocked by my network. I will try to review the information later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your coding has some little problems.for example you don't need to define `dayOfWeek_array` every second.this makes your app slow.so put it out of your `looptime` function.and better to use `uint` type instead of `Number` for variables that won't contain decimal numbers.

This is the full code(AM/PM system).you can copy this:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;

var looper:Timer=new Timer(1000);

var dayOfWeek_array:Array = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"); 


var time:Date;
//use uint type instead of number for these vars.because they won't contain decimals!

var month:uint;
var day:uint;
var year:uint; 


var hour:String;
var minute:String;     
var day_str:String;

var hour12:uint;
var AM_PM:Object;




looper.start();
looper.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, looptime)

//execute the function when starting app
looptime(null);

function looptime(event:TimerEvent):void{
    time=new Date();

    month=time.getMonth();
    day=  time.getDate()+1;
    year= time.getFullYear();

    hour12=time.getHours()>11?time.getHours()-12:time.getHours();
    AM_PM=String(time.getHours()>11?" PM":" AM");
    time.getMonth();

    hour= hour12>9?String(hour12):"0"+String(hour12);
    minute=time.getMinutes()>9?String(time.getMinutes()):"0"+String(time.getMinutes());
    day_str=dayOfWeek_array[time.getDay()]


    Day_txt.text = day_str;
    Date_txt.text = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;

    Time_txt.text = hour + ":" + minute+AM_PM;
}
```

Hope this helps.☺

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Bingo!!! Thank you soooo much. This works. I tried the code and at first I received an error message so I back tracked and realized that I did not have a name instance defined for Date_txt (go figure) after correcting this it worked great. The only thing is that I still didnt see AM or PM at the end so I checked the code you sent me and corrected a couple of spacing issues for the string and Voila!!! All is well. Thanks again for this.

Comment: You're welcome.I'm glad I could help.so why you don't mark(tick) my answer?

Comment: you said "All is well".so why you don't accept and tick my answer?

Comment: I am not sure how to accept your answer, I didn't see an option to do so. I would be glad to do so.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks again